# ascii package printing unnecessary characters

Tags: r

Running the following example

```
require(ascii)
mat <- matrix(c(1,11,2,12),nrow=2)
rownames(mat)<-letters[1:2]
colnames(mat)<-letters[11:12]
tab<- as.table(mat)
ascitab <- ascii(tab,digits=0,align="r")
print(ascitab,type="t2t")
```

produces the following output:

```
||     |    k |    l 
|   a |    1 |    2 
|   b |   11 |   12 
Warning messages:
1: In rep(rownames, length = nrow(x)) :
  'x' is NULL so the result will be NULL
2: In rep(colnames, length = ncol(x)) :
  'x' is NULL so the result will be NULL
```

There are 2 issues:

The double vertical bar at the very beginning is incorrect, it should only be one bar.
And the warnings are very strange. The table has a sensible format.

Changing the print statement to

```
print(ascitab,type="t2t",include.rownames=TRUE,include.colnames=TRUE)
```

does not solve the problem.
Can anybody help?

I know a clumsy solution which includes capturing and postprocessing the output,
but I would like to see a clean solution.

Comment: The Examples from the `?ascii` doc are not better. They exhibit the same problems. Clearly, something wrong and worth sending to the maintainer of that package.

Comment: These warnings does not occur for me. But I have such warnings when using ascii in a Shiny app. Note than `include.rownames` is an option of `ascii()`, not `print()`.

Comment: Looking for an answer to this myself (the error msgs). I've not gotten around it except for specifying both `include.row/colnames` *and* `row/colnames = blah`. For me, I tend to use `rownames = rep(NA, nrow(df))` and `colnames = names(df)`. I don't get why if I use `include.rownames = F` I need to specify rownames, though.

Comment: There's a [similar report](https://github.com/eusebe/ascii/issues/17) at a github repo for the `ascii` package (not sure if it's the CRAN author or forked), but I can confirm that installing the git version with `devtools` does not print the row/colnames error.